# Apollo cache error on deleted "child" table

Tags: apollo-client

NOTE:  the __typename Client below refers to a person (like a customer) - not client/server.

Getting the following error:
Cache data may be lost when replacing the clientServices field of a Client object.

To address this problem (which is not a bug in Apollo Client), define a custom merge function for the Client.clientServices field, so InMemoryCache can safely merge these objects:

```
  existing: [{"__ref":"ClientService:46"}]
  incoming: []
```

What's happening is that I've deleted a "child" record - so there's no data.

```
First time I get this returned.  Note: there's info associated with field clientServices
    {
    "client": {
        "id": "41",
        "companyId": "3",
        "firstName": "Lew",
        "lastName": "Terry",
        "email": "lewterry@diamond.com",
        "clientServices": [
            {
                "id": "46",
                "serviceId": "13",
                "description": "Individual psychotherapy - 45 minutes",
                "sessionFee": 90,
                "cptCode": "90834",
                "__typename": "ClientService"
            }
        ],
        "__typename": "Client"
    }
}


And here's the results on a refetch after the client record is saved and the clientServices "child" data has been deleted so it's an empty array.

{
    "client": {
        "id": "41",
        "companyId": "3",
        "firstName": "Lew",
        "lastName": "Terry",
        "email": "lewterry@diamond.com",
    clientServices: []
        "__typename": "Client"
    }
}
```

Do I really need a custom merge?  Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same proble and found [the solution here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6451#issuecomment-646087140).

First solution is to remove the old `clientServices` and save a new one.

So for your case it'd be something like this:

```
cache.evict({
        id: 'client:41',
        fieldName: 'clientServices',
        broadcast: false,
});
```

This would remove the `clientServices` field from the `client` and then save into cache a new `clientServices` (in your particular case, an empty array).

Another solution is to modify the cache directly.

```
cache.modify({
       id: 'client:41',
       fields: {
         clientServices: (clientServices, { readField }) => {
           return clientServices.filter(
             (clientService) => readField('id', clientService) !== 46
           );
         },
       },
});
```

Hope this helps.